# Javascript function works only once

Tags: javascript

I've got a function which should get all inputs from site, add their values multiplied by their amounts and then replace a string inside  with the result. The problem is the function executes only once or sometimes it's never executed. Its code is:

```
function calcTotal() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var total = 0;

    var priceString = null;
    var e = null;
    var price = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        e = inputs[i].value;
        priceString = "hidden_" + inputs[i].name;
        if (e.match(/[0-9\.]/)) {
            var price = document.getElementById(priceString).innerHTML;
            total = total + parseFloat(e) * parseFloat(price);
        }

    }
    var totalString = document.getElementById("total");
    var stringToDisplay = total.toFixed(2);
    totalString.innerHTML = stringToDisplay.toString();
}
```

The function should replace this span: `<span id="total">0.00</span>`

The function is called on each input's change by code:

```
<?php foreach($allPremium as $premiumItem){?>
<?php $ceny[$premiumItem->type]=$premiumItem->price;?>
<div class="premium-pack-item">
<?php echo $premiumItem->name;?>
<br />
<?php echo $premiumItem->description;?>
<br />
<?php echo "&euro; ".number_format($premiumItem->price, 2);?>
<br />
<span id="hidden_amount_<?php echo $premiumItem->type;?>" style="display:none"><?php echo $premiumItem->price;?></span>
<input onkeypress="calcTotal()" type="number" size=1 name="amount_<?php echo $premiumItem->type;?>">
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Could you explain me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: The function is called by
<input onkeypress="calcTotal()" type="number" size=1 name="amount_<?php echo $premiumItem->type;?>">

Comment: Please show relevant HTML.

Comment: I've added html snippets into question.

Comment: Please print the HTML after the PHP has been processed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you put in the generated HTML that the browser sees (View/Source in the brower), NOT the PHP?  There are many times more people who can help you by reading the HTML, than those trying to understand what your PHP is doing, myself included.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I'll edit the question asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if you are getting any javascript error using Developers Tools, that might reveal real cause.

Comment: I don't know why you're downvoted. Usage of Developers Tools from IE showed me "null" when I was trying to get innerHTML. The Firebug and Chrome didn't show the issue. I have made very stupid mistake because I put "name" property instead of "id" into span in 2 of 3 loops where I used it. The rest of code works at all. Thank you all for help!